# How to get position of clicked image in ListView when settag is already used

Tags: android, google-maps, custom-adapter

I am trying to load a map image using maps.googleapis.com in my custom adapter.  I use a BitmapLruCache and keep track of the url of my image by using `imageView.setTag(imageUrl);` to make sure the correct image gets loaded when returned.

Now, I'm trying to allow the user to click on the map to load Google Maps for that location.  My question is, how can I get the position, so I can get the correct address to send when I'm already using the imageView's tag?

```
MyLocation location = data.get(position);
int mapSize = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_thumb_size);
String mapImageUrl = GoogleStaticMaps.getImageURL(location.getAddress1(), location.getCity(), location.getState(), mapSize, mapSize);
if (mapImageUrl != null) {
    imageMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new BitmapService(mContext, imageMap, mapImageUrl, "");
//    line that would normally give me my position, but messes up my image
//    imageMap.settag(position);
    imageMap.setOnClickListener(onMapClickListener);                
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is what I ended up doing in the OnClickListener as per @greenapps suggestion:

`ViewGroup parentLayout = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
 int position = (Integer) parentLayout.getTag();
 MyLocation location = data.get(position);`

In your getView() just add:

`//get parent of ImageView and set its tag to the position of the row
 LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_layout_map);
 parentLayout.setTag(position);`

Comment: You are not setting a tag in your code, nor are you reading one. What do you mean with `position` exactly?

Comment: The `BitmapService` sets the tag of imageMap to mapImageUrl so that when the image is asynchronously returned, it ends up in the correct ImageView in the adapter.  My `onMapClickListener` is what will eventually need to use `v.getTag()` to get the position of the data.

Comment: If you set position as tag the bitmap service could not determine the url from it?

Comment: Why aren't you setting an on click listener on the list view?

Comment: @greenapps because the image is one of multiple clickable items in the row.

Comment: You can set position as tag in the parent of the imageview. The parent will be the view you return in getView().

Comment: Probably you will already have used the tag for a holder. No problem add a position member to your holder class.

Comment: Yes!  So this worked.  Thank you.  Question has been edited to include details of answer. I assume since my ImageView is 3 Linear/RelativeLayouts down, is why I had to do so many `getParents()`?  Complicated view indeed.  Not sure if this is the best way, but for my situation it works.  Thanks.  Please add as answer and I will mark as so.

Comment: You could have tagged the parent of the imageview. Then one getParent() was enough. But anyhow problem solved.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for the back and forth, but this is ultimately a cleaner solution, I will change the edit.